# How do I format datetime values to more friendly formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails. I created a blog using SQLite3, because I am unable to install MySQL, and would like to display the date of creation next to the title.

The date of creation is created using a timestamp. As I am new to RoR I created the blog using `generate scaffold` so I'm not 100% sure how that all works.

At the moment, when I display the `created_at` field, I'm given an ugly format:

```
2011-12-05 14:11:10 UTC
```

Is there a way to change this so that it display `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM`, or preferably to say "`posted 30 days ago`". I realize the latter would be a lot more tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: you will have to install something other than SQLite (I recommend PostgreSQL, not MySQL). SQLite is unsuitable for production, and you don't really want your dev and production DB servers to be different.

To your question: Ruby and Rails have lots of date formatting methods. `to_s` might do what you want, or there's things like `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper.time_ago_in_words`.

Comment: How exactly would I implement this? I must repeat that I'm very new to RoR and only very slightly getting used to how everything works together...

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: I'm not familiar as to how I would implement what you mentioned above... from what I've worked with so far I'm guessing I would create a helper (?!), but at the moment I'm at a stage where I'm stumbling through it so I can't be sure.

Comment: You don't need to create a helper. `DateHelper` is already created. Just call `time_ago_in_words(created_at)` or `created_at.to_s`. Do you understand?

Comment: I see. I used <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> to display the date nicely. Thanks for your help, it looks grand :)

Comment: Excellent! Why not choose this as the answer, then? :)

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Check out Haml when you get a chance. It's nicer than ERb.

Comment: Question: answered!! Again (apologies), but what does this (Haml) mean? :)

Comment: I disagree that the OP needs to switch from SQLite to PostgreSQL. The database is largely abstracted by ActiveRecord or an ORM, which is one of the raison d'être for ORMs. For dev work I have found SQLite to be excellent because it is easily set up, especially when you consider it allows in-memory DBs, and easy management. I love PostgreSQL but there is a time and place for each.

Comment: @howardrocks, [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) is a great shorthand for generating HTML. It isn't liked in some circles because it's one more thing to learn, but for things I do it's very useful.

Comment: The Tin Man: Sort of correct -- to a point. If you're using any DB features beyond the most basic, you really need to use something other than SQLite -- there are too many things it doesn't support. At that point, it makes sense to use the same DB for dev and production.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks Tin Man. For now, and at the early stage I am SQLite seems to be working how I need. When/if I get to a point when I have the knowledge to know that it's hindering me, I'll feel like I've achieved something :)

Comment: howardrocks: You can't use SQLite for production reliably (due to its not really being a multiuser database), so you *must* switch before then. Also, you should learn *now* how it's hindering you: you *must* learn to use the DB properly. (Example: SQLite has no foreign key constraint support and no proper Boolean type.)

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for `strftime` - ruby documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Time.now
irb(main):002:0> a.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
=> "05-12-2011 15:08"
```

Comment: +1. [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime), [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) and [`Time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime) support `strftime`, which is the workhorse function when it comes to creating various output formats.